# Unbound DNS Server, Python module: inspect response message elements

Tags: python, dns

## Goal

I would like to leverage Unbound Python module to examine the response just before it's dispatched to the client. Primarily, I'm interested in the `;; ANSWER SECTION:`, i.e. to which IP address the query got resolved to.

## Problem

What had looked like a trivial modification of [logDnsMsg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/pythonmod/examples/log.py#L57) function turned out to be a dounting task of browsing [`reply_info`](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/48ee1e3d00db8189207678162c9326e093678d92/util/data/msgreply.h#L102), `rrset_ref` and `ub_packed_rrset_key` structures in pursuit of the desired `;; ANSWER SECTION:` bytes.

The reason is the [logDnsMsg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/pythonmod/examples/log.py#L57) function does not work as expected for `A` queries `;; ANSWER SECTION:`, while it suprisingly operates as expected for `;; AUTHORITY SECTION:` on `AAAA` queries.

Lemme demonstrate a comparison between the Python implemented [logDnsMsg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/pythonmod/examples/log.py#L57) function and a native [log_dns_msg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/48ee1e3d00db8189207678162c9326e093678d92/util/data/msgreply.c#L767) function; with the former displaying a gibberish and the latter performing exactly as expected. Both functions are called from within the Python module context as follows:

```
+++
def operate(id, event, qstate, qdata):
    log_info("pythonmod: operate called, id: %d, event:%s" % (id, strmodulevent(event)))
    if (qstate.return_msg):
        logDnsMsg(qstate)
        log_dns_msg("blackpie KARMMMMMM XXXXXXX", qstate.return_msg.qinfo, qstate.return_msg.rep)
+++
```

Note that I altered the original [logDnsMsg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/pythonmod/examples/log.py#L57) so as it uses the logging framework in favour of `print`. The output was the same for `print` but for being scattered across the logfile at buffer's discretion.

`dig` output:

```
karm@localhost:~$ dig seznam.cz  @127.0.0.1 -p53535
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-18.P2.fc20 <<>> seznam.cz @127.0.0.1 -p53535
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38630
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;seznam.cz.     IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
seznam.cz.    300 IN  A 77.75.76.3
;; Query time: 656 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53535(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 25 16:04:32 CEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

Output for `AAAA` query, `;; AUTHORITY SECTION:` looks decent enough from both [logDnsMsg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/pythonmod/examples/log.py#L57) and [log_dns_msg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/48ee1e3d00db8189207678162c9326e093678d92/util/data/msgreply.c#L767):

```
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: pythonmod: operate called, id: 1, event:module_event_moddone
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: Query: e.root-servers.net., type: AAAA (28), class: IN (1) 
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: Return    reply :: flags: 8080, QDcount: 1, Security:0, TTL=86400
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info:           qinfo :: qname: ['e', 'root-servers', 'net', ''] e.root-servers.net., qtype: AAAA, qclass: IN
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: Reply:
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: 0:['root-servers', 'net', ''] root-servers.net. flags: 0004
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: type:SOA (6) class:IN (1)
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info:   0:TTL=3600000
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: 
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info:        0x00 | 00 40 01 61 0C 72 6F 6F 74 2D 73 65 72 76 65 72 73 | . @ . a . r o o t - s e r v e r s 
       0x10 | 73 03 6E 65 74 00 05 6E 73 74 6C 64 0C 76 65 72 69 | s . n e t . . n s t l d . v e r i 
       0x20 | 69 73 69 67 6E 2D 67 72 73 03 63 6F 6D 00 78 0C E3 | i s i g n - g r s . c o m . x . . 
       0x30 | E3 24 00 00 38 40 00 00 1C 20 00 12 75 00 00 36 EE | . $ . . 8 @ . . .   . . u . . 6 . 
       0x40 | EE 80                                              | . . 
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: blackpie KARMMMMMM XXXXXXX ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 0
;; flags: qr ra ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0 
;; QUESTION SECTION:
e.root-servers.net. IN  AAAA
;; ANSWER SECTION:
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
root-servers.net. 3600000 IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2014110500 14400 7200 1209600 3600000
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] debug: mesh_run: python module exit state is module_finished
```

On the contrary, for `A` query, `;; ANSWER SECTION:` is completely useless as far as [logDnsMsg](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/pythonmod/examples/log.py#L57) goes:

```
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: pythonmod: operate called, id: 1, event:module_event_moddone
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: Query: seznam.cz., type: A (1), class: IN (1) 
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: Return    reply :: flags: 8080, QDcount: 1, Security:0, TTL=300
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info:           qinfo :: qname: ['seznam', 'cz', ''] seznam.cz., qtype: A, qclass: IN
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: Reply:
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: 0:['seznam', 'cz', ''] seznam.cz. flags: 0000
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: type:A (1) class:IN (1)
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info:   0:TTL=300
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: 
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info:        0x00 | 00 04 4D 4B 4C 03                                  | . . M K L . 
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] info: blackpie KARMMMMMM XXXXXXX ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 0
;; flags: qr ra ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0 
;; QUESTION SECTION:
seznam.cz.  IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
seznam.cz.  300 IN  A 77.75.76.3
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
[1429970672] unbound[14053:0] debug: mesh_run: python module exit state is module_finished
```

Note the `00 04 4D 4B 4C 03` bytes that are erroneously interpreted as ASCII.

## Question

Where in the `struct ub_packed_rrset_key** rrsets;` one finds the desired `;; ANSWER SECTION:` data? (If it is indeed the right place to look.)

I've been fiddling with it for quite some time without any luck. I examined the [`sldns_wire2str_pkt_scan`](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/dbb2756d46f5e80b1cf9194bcd0264b82818bbf0/sldns/wire2str.c#L328) function that is used internally for unpacking the `wire` binary data, but I am none the wiser.

Comment: I add python tag to your question, If it's wrong remove it ;).

Comment: @shA.t I'm not sure it's actually a Python issue per se, but why not.  "Unbound" tag will be the most appropriate; I don't have the reputation to create it though.

Answer (score 1):

`logDnsMsg()` is logging a [hex dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) of the contents of each DNS resource record.  It outputs the bytes alongside their ASCII interpretation (with `.`s for non-printable bytes).  This means that if the data contains ASCII strings these will be visible in the output, while other types of data (like IP addresses) will not translate to meaningful text.

The first two bytes of the data are the `RDLENGTH` field, indicating the length of the record data.  The remaining bytes are the `RDATA` field proper.  The interpretation of these bytes depends on the record type.  `A` records consist of a single 32-bit IP address, so they are easy to parse.

The following example code prints the contents of an `A` record:

```
def print_a_record(data):
    rdlength, rdata = data[:2], data[2:]
    assert rdlength == '\x00\x04'
    assert len(rdata) == 4
    addr_bytes = [ord(c) for c in rdata]
    print('{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(*addr_bytes))
```

Further information:

- [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), Wikipedia
- [RFC 1035 - Domain Names - Implementation and Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), IETF